# svn2git with local repo?

Tags: git, svn, migration

Let's say some time ago I checked out a SVN repo:

svn co http://example.com/repo

Now I have the folder $HOME/repo which contains `.svn` subfolders about the metadata of the repo in the `whatever` host.

Let's say that http://example.com goes down.

At this point, can I migrate my local SVN checkout to GIT?

The [docs about svn2git migration](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) only mention dealing with remote http repos, and the solution of serving my own repo via svnserve suggested [here](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/68) doesn't seem to work (`svn: E210005: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost'`).

So, should I lose hope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN is a server-based version control system.  Locally you only have the version that you have checked out.  Without access to the server you can't convert that to git and get the history, because you do not have access to that when you are offline.

It would be easy enough to add the working copy you have into git.

A simple method might to do something like this.

- Create a copy of your SVN working copy and remove all the `.svn` cruft rsync -Cva current_wc/ new_wc
- cd into the clean working copy and do a `git init`, and `git add .`, and `git commit`.